# $( y \ln y dx + x \ln y dy) - e^{-xy} dx + \frac{dy}{y} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation : $$ ( y \ln y dx + x \ln y dy) - e^{-xy} dx + \frac{dy}{y} = 0$$

**My attempt :** It is clear that this differential equation  is not exact .

I did some minor calculation and went up to
$$e^{xy} d(xy) - \frac{dx}{\ln y} + \frac{e^{xy} d(\ln y)}{\ln y} = 0$$

I can not go further. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you expect this to be in closed form? It looks like the system could benefit from a change of variables. $u = xy$ and $v = \ln y$ come to mind. Not sure how much that will help though.

Comment: It can be further simplified as $$
d (e^{xy}) - \frac{dx}{\ln y} + e^{xy} d(\ln (\ln y)) = 0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(y\ln(y)-e^{-xy})+(\frac{1}{y}+x\ln(y))\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
Multiply both sides by $e^{xy}$ and re-arrange $$\big[ye^{xy}\ln(y)+\frac{dy}{dx}\big(xe^{xy}\ln(y)+\frac{e^{xy}}{y}\big)\big]-1=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(e^{xy}\ln(y)\big)-1=0$$
Thus $${e^{xy}\ln(y)-x=c_{1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$( y \ln y dx + x \ln y dy) - e^{-xy} dx + \frac{dy}{y} = 0$$
$$\ln y d(xy) - e^{-xy} dx + {d\ln y} = 0$$
$$e^{xy} \ln y d(xy)  + e^{xy} {d\ln y} -dx=0$$
$$\ln y d(e^{xy})  + e^{xy} {d\ln y} - dx=0$$
$$ d(e^{xy}\ln y)-dx=0$$
$$ d(e^{xy}\ln y-x)=0$$
Integrate.
$$ e^{xy}\ln y-x=C$$